# Angular-xeditable disable rendering the particular element to editable mode

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-xeditable

Below is the sample Code availabe in the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/NfPcH/19061/) I am trying to achieve my use case.
In this table, I will have one more column as first column which is an checkbox. On selecting the "Edit" button, only the selected checkbox rows from the table should show editable mode and other rows should display as static text. Is it possible to achieve it. Can anyone help me in this to meet my requirement.

```
<h4>Angular-xeditable Editable row (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold">
      <td style="width:35%">Name</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Status</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Group</td>
      <td style="width:25%">Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>
        <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
        <span editable-text="user.name" e-name="name" e-form="rowform" e-ng-hide="true" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)" e-required>
        <span ng-hide="false">hello</span>
          {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
        <span editable-select="user.status" e-name="status" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
          {{ showStatus(user) }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
        <span editable-select="user.group" e-name="group" onshow="loadGroups()" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups">
          {{ showGroup(user) }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <!-- form -->
        <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveUser($data, user.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == user">
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
            save
          </button>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
            cancel
          </button>
        </form>
        <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">del</button>
        </div>  
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser()">Add row</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? what is the issue?

Comment: I have tried using e-disabled option for disabling the edit mode. But it was going to edit mode and making it as readOnly mode